# Trouble trying to connect the database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have installed XAMPP which as you know automatically installs Apache , PHP and MySQL , that's the reason why I don't know my user name and password when I am trying to conect the database using PHP file. I have written this PHP function which has to connect to the database:

http://postimg.org/image/wgq35omfd/

I have entered phpMyAdmin and have seen the users and I see one named root , I know the server is called localhost but I don't know the pasword and I can't pass the correct data to the database connect function mysql_pconnect("localhost" , "root", pass ) and that's why my function always returns false. How can I check which are the username and the pasword to pass it to the mysql_pconnect function.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score -1):

If you've entered phpMyAdmin you should know your username and password. Use those. If you entered phpMyAdmin without a password then the password should be blank. (Try to put a password on it tho.)

Comment: So if my password is blank I have to type the mysql_pconect function like that

mysql_pconect("localhost" , "root");

Is that right?

Comment: I don't use the pconnect function myself, but I found it is going to be deprecated soon (or already is).
Try this instead, it has some nice documentation aswell.http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: Typing like that mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" ); 
is still giving me error .

Comment: Try putting NULL as the password (without "") Like this ('localhost', 'root', NULL, 'dbname')

Comment: It's telling me that the database is unknown when I have entered the phpAdmin and I have seen the database.

Comment: Did you fill in the 'dbname'? Try with the same capital letters.

Comment: Yes I filled in the dbname. What do you mean by "Try with the same capital letters."

Comment: If your db is named DBname also type DBname and not dbName.
If it still doesn't work post some code.

Comment: Yes I am typing the exact same name in the mysql_conect function.
Here is my function 
http://postimg.org/image/5wjwkfdpp/
and it always returns false

Comment: `//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$table = "DbName";
$selected = mysql_select_db($table, $dbhandle) or die("Could not select database");`

Comment: Where do I have to put that ? In my db_connect function?

Comment: Try only that, if you have no messages on your screen it works now. You don't really need a function for what you are doing.

Comment: OK , but where do I put what you've typed in ?

Comment: at the moment u are tyring to connect to ur database, you could but it in the function if u wish. I always use an include.